# How do I update an SVG text element using Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I'm using Snap.svg to load an SVG image and add text elements to it. However, I need to be able to update the text elements as the page loads.

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
var svg = Snap("#selector");
var text;
Snap.load(path_to_file, function(f) {
    svg.append(f);
    var g = svg.select("g");
    text = g.text(x_pos, y_pos, label);
}
```

Let's say I want to update the text later, how do I do this? I am guaranteed to update the `text` object after it's been created after calling `load`.

The only way I've managed to modify the text is by setting an `id` to the element and then doing it with jQuery like this:

`self.selector.find("#my_id")[0].textContent = "New text";`

However, this feels really wrong and I think I might just be missing something with the Snap API.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think it should be as simple as

```
text.attr({ text: 'my new text'});
```

so

```
setTimeout( function() { text.attr({ text: 'my new text'}) }, 2000 );
```

would test it

Comment: This does not work for me. However, if I do `text.attr({"#text", "my new text"});`, then it works.

Comment: This doesn't sound right and sounds like a bug. Maybe post up a jsfiddle if you want to double check it.

Comment: @Djip The `'text'` var in your example may in-fact be a `tspan` element. Calling `text.parent().attr({text: "new Text'})` will just replace the whole tspan (attributes and all) with raw text, so that's not necessarily great either, but will confirm what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, you can directly get a reference of DOM node using `Element.node`, so you can mess around

```
text.node.textContent = "New text";
text.node.innerHTML = "New text";
text.node.innerHTML = 'a<tspan dy="5">2</tspan>'
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```
$(s.select('#id').node).text('new text');
```

Comment: A sentence or two of explanation goes a long way towards making a possibly correct answer into a great one.